# python-difflib.SequenceMatcher can't compare with three byte

Tags: python

I want to compare the full-width forms between two string , but use difflib.SequenceMatcher that has a problem.
my code is

```
aa = "ａｂｃｄｆｇｒ"

bb = "ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈ"

s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,aa,bb)

e=round(s.ratio(),4)*100

print e

for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():

print tag,i1,i2,j1,j2

print aa[i1:i2]

print bb[j1:j2]
```

but it print out like this

```
88.89

equal 0 14 0 14

ａｂｃｄïﾽ

ａｂｃｄïﾽ

insert 14 14 14 17



ﾅïﾽ

equal 14 20 17 23

ﾆｇïﾽ

ﾆｇïﾽ

replace 20 21 23 24

ﾒ

ﾈ
```

I think the difflib.SequenceMatcher may compare a byte one by one , have anyway can let the difflib.SequenceMatcher compare three byte in once times? Or anyway can let the compare smoothly but still can use `ratio()` and `get_opcodes()` function. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The SequenceMatcher can compare sequences of hashable objects. They do not have to be strings. Thus, it is possible to compare sequnces of 3-tuples, where the 3-tuples are tuples of 3 bytes.

You can group the bytes in a string into groups of 3 using the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
In [23]: aa = "ａｂｃｄｆｇｒ"

In [24]: zip(*[iter(aa)]*3)
Out[24]: 
[('\xef', '\xbd', '\x81'),
 ('\xef', '\xbd', '\x82'),
 ('\xef', '\xbd', '\x83'),
 ('\xef', '\xbd', '\x84'),
 ('\xef', '\xbd', '\x86'),
 ('\xef', '\xbd', '\x87'),
 ('\xef', '\xbd', '\x92')]
```

Note that on my machine the `str`, `aa`, is being interpreted as being encoded in UTF-8. Your result may look different depending on your encoding.

Use `itertools.izip_longest` instead of `zip` if you want to handle strings whose lengths are not multiples of 3. `zip` omits the remainder.

---

```
import difflib
aa = "ａｂｃｄｆｇｒ"
bb = "ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈ"

print(repr(aa))
print(repr(bb))

aaa = zip(*[iter(aa)]*3)
bbb = zip(*[iter(bb)]*3)
print(len(aa), len(bb))
s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, aaa, bbb)

e=round(s.ratio(),4)*100

print e

for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():    
    print tag,i1,i2,j1,j2    
    print aaa[i1:i2]    
    print bbb[j1:j2]
```